# async.series doesn't execute the second function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-modules, async.js

I'm trying to use async.series to execute 2 functions in different files in sequential mode.
The use case is to download log files to the local and then move them into a folder.

The functions work fine individually.
Now my next step is to require these 2 files in index.js and call both the functions in sequence.

This is the code to write the files from webdav into local machine:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream');
const util = require('util');
const pipeline = util.promisify(stream.pipeline);
const { createClient } = require("webdav");
const path = require("path");
const client = createClient(
    "https:/*/webdav/Sites/Logs", {
        username: "*",
        password: "*"
    }
);
async function writeFiles(){
    console.log('inside write functions');
    let directoryData = await client.getDirectoryContents("/");
        console.log('after directorydata' +directoryData);
    await Promise.all(directoryData.map(start));
      
}
async function start(dir) {
    let  fileName = dir.filename;
    console.log('inside start function');
    var directory = path.join(__dirname,'/logs/') 
    if(fileName.includes('.log')){

        try {
            let fileName = dir.filename;
            //console.log(fileName);
            await pipeline(
            client.createReadStream(fileName),
            fs.createWriteStream(directory + fileName)
            );
            return directory;
            console.log('done');
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        
} 
}
module.exports = writeFiles;
```

This is the code to create folders and move the log files into them according to the name:

```js
const testFolder = './logs/';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
var directory = path.join(__dirname,'/logs/');
async function sort (){
    console.log('inside sort function sorting file');
    await fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
        //console.log('sdcfe');
        if(files){
            console.log('filesss')
        } else {
            console.log('no filesss')
        }
    files.forEach(file => {
    let fileFolder = file.split('-')[0];
    var folder = fileFolder.replace('.', "");
    var dir = directory+folder;
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
        //console.log('inside if' + dir);
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
    } 
    const currentPath = path.join(directory, file);
    const destinationPath = path.join(directory, folder, file);
    fs.rename(currentPath, destinationPath, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err
        } else {
            return destinationPath;
               console.log("Successfully moved the file!");
        }
    });
});
});

}
module.exports = sort;
```

This is the index.js file to require both the above files and call them in sequence (once the write function is done, I need to move the logs files into folders)

```js
'use strict';

// Initialize constants
const async = require('async');


const writeFiles = require('./webdavConnect2');
const sort = require('./sortingFiles');


// Initialize the program
let program = require('commander');

// Initialize the version
program.version('0.5.0');


program
    .command('say')
    .description('Batch command that can be used to zip, upload, import, and re-index for a given site import.')
    .action(function () {
        function webdavConnect() {
            console.log('inside webdav function');
             // write the files into local machine
            writeFiles();
         }

         // move the files into folders
         function sortingFiles() {
            console.log('inside sort function');
            
            sort();
             
         }
        
        async.series([
            function(callback) {
            webdavConnect(function(directory){
           callback(null, directory);
       })
       },
       function(callback) { sortingFiles(function(destinationPath){
           callback(null,destinationPath);
       })
       }
            

            ], function(asyncErrorObj) {

            // Was an error defined?  If so, then throw it
            if (asyncErrorObj !== null) { throw asyncErrorObj; }

            
            
            console.log('END');

        });

    });


// Parse the command-line arguments
program.parse();
```

The issue with this is that currently the first function executes and not the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a solution a friend suggested:

I pinpointed some issues regarding the usage of async.series . Try to replace your index.js with the following code. Note the async functions that are now being passed to async.series, and note how those functions now accept the callback that Async.js is supposed to pass to them which are missing in the current code. I couldn't test this because the project is not reproducable (at least without a major prep). If anything breaks you can share another message and/or tag me directly! Hope it helps.

```
"use strict";

const async = require("async");
const writeFiles = require("./webdavConnect2");
const sort = require("./sortingFiles");
let program = require("commander");

program.version("0.5.0");

program
  .command("say")
  .description(
    "Batch command that can be used to zip, upload, import, and re-index for a given site import."
  )
  .action(function () {
    async function webdavConnect(callback) {
      callback(await writeFiles());
    }

    async function sortingFiles(callback) {
      callback(await sort());
    }

    async.series(
      [
        function (callback) {
          webdavConnect(function (directory) {
            callback(null, directory);
          });
        },
        function (callback) {
          sortingFiles(function (destinationPath) {
            callback(null, destinationPath);
          });
        }
      ],
      function (asyncErrorObj, results) {
        if (asyncErrorObj !== null) {
          throw asyncErrorObj;
        }
        console.log(results);
      }
    );
  });

program.parse();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that both functions are async and they should be called in async function with await. First function did not completed the execution and second started its execution but as it did not find the files so you can't see the output for second function. This is what i would do to fix execution issue:

```
"use strict";

const writeFiles = require("./webdavConnect2");
const sort = require("./sortingFiles");

// Initialize the program
let program = require("commander");

// Initialize the version
program.version("0.5.0");

program
  .command("say")
  .description(
    "Batch command that can be used to zip, upload, import, and re-index for a given site import."
  )
  .action(async function() {
    await writeFiles();
    await sort();
  });

// Parse the command-line arguments
program.parse();
```